# Ajax/PHP contact form issue

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm building an ajax/php contact form for my project with the following fields:

**Name (required), Email (required), Subject (Not required) and Website (Not required)**

Everything's working fine the only problem now is if the user doesn't type anything in **Subject** and or **Website** fields the email I receive shows those 2 fields like so:

**Subject: (shows blank)**

**Website: (shows blank)**

Is it possible not to show those 2 fields at all if the user didn't type anything so on the email I receive I only get:

**Name: [user name]**

**Email: [user email address]**

I'm just posting the PHP code as I believe it's something to do with PHP only and not the Ajax script:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// SUBJECT
$subject = $_POST["subject"];

// WEBSITE
$website = $_POST["website"];

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "email@myemail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Website: ";
$Body .= $website;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: It may have something to do with PHP but not in the code you shared. Try debugging further to locate where the word "blank" is added to empty fields.

Comment: the word blank doesn't show I typed blank meaning the fields are empty. I just edited that part of the question for better understanding ;)

Comment: Have you tried to set up any validation checks on your input fields?

Comment: Only the Name and Email have validations

Answer (score 1):

You can check for conditions with an `if` statement.  Something like this:

```
if (!empty($subject)) {
    $Body .= "Subject: ";
    $Body .= $subject;
    $Body .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: On the email received it still shows the word Subject:  and the word Website:  What I want is to remove these 2 fields completely if the user didn't type anything in them. Thanks!

Comment: @Tiago: Then you're going to need to debug a little to find out what's actually in the `$subject` and `$website` variables.  They may not be completely empty, but may have whitespace characters that you want to check for.  Either way, the way you check for a condition in code is with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `formData`, so `disabling` the field won't work.

If you want to get rid of empty variables, build the data according to a condition like this

```
function submitForm() {

    var data = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    }

    if($("#subject").val() !== "") {
        data.subject = $("#subject").val()
    }

    if($("#website").val() !== "") {
        data.website = $("#website").val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(text) {
            if (text == "success") {
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false, text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but on the email received it still shows the word Subject: and the word Website: What I want is to remove these 2 fields completely if the user didn't type anything in them. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any javascript code to submit the form ? Or do you only use basic `<form action="process.php">` ?

Comment: On the email I receive what I get now is: Name: (the user name)
Email:(the user email)
Website: NO_WEBSITE
Subject: NO_SUBJECT
Message: (The user message)

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure where exactly paste that code. Here's my fiddle link:  fiddle.jshell.net/L7ps8d0t could you update the code there if that's alright? Thanks!

Comment: Inside your `submitForm()` function. Please see new update :D

Comment: The words Subject: and Website: still show but this time they show blank even if I type anything in them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98417/discussion-between-tiago-and-david).

Comment: Ah, the problem was instead of writing `!==`, I wrote `===`. New update ! :D

Comment: I still get the same issue

Comment: With the code in my answer,  `$_POST['website']` is null if `website` is not set. What is the problem yet ?